# Accessing features from checkboxes that are inside Leaflet popup

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw, leaflet-geoman

I'm working in leaflet, and I'm drawing a polygon with the  [Leaflet PM plugin](https://github.com/codeofsumit/leaflet.pm)

On I finish the drawing I run the following event

```
mymap.on('pm:create', function(e) {
    var strPopup = '<input type="checkbox" id="cbx1" class="cbx" name="objects" value="eraser">';
    strPopup += '<input type="checkbox" id="cbx2" class="cbx" name="objects" value="pencil">';
    strPopup += '<button id="btnSave" class="btn" onclick="foundObjects()" >Save</button>';
    e.layer.bindPopup(strPopup);
    e.layer.openPopup();
}
```

So, when the user clicks the 'Save' button, I'm trying to read the values of the checkboxes with jQuery:

```
function foundObjects(){
    console.log( $('#cbx1').attr('checked'))
    console.log( $('#cbx2').attr('value'))
}
```

However both results appears in Console as 'undefined'. Someone has a hint, why is it happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this same issue and I was able to solve it using pure javascript

```
function check() {
    document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = true;
}

function uncheck() {
    document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far As I know you need to use `.prop("checked")` instead of `.attr("checked")`